# How check if the directory is exist? read to the end

Tags: java, android

Program should check if the directory is exist?? And if not, tell the user that there is no such folder.

I found many examples in which is explained how to check whether there is a file, but I need to know whether there is a directory? All methods

```
boolean x = context.getExternalFilesDir("/nicknameOfUser/").exists();
Toast.makeText(context, "ExternalFilesDir : " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`isAbsolute()`, `isDirectory()`, `isFile()`, create a new path to the files folder - nicknameOfUser I do not want to they were created, I just need to receive there is a directory or not ... I don't need create new folders...

**How to do it?** I think it is a question from regular, but I can't understand ...

When i launch app first time - in my filemanager no any file! But after i check `.exists();` it create a path to the folder that i need a check... I DON'T NEED IT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually i found a solution. I begin to think it is impossible but all is ok

```
String fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/nicknameOfUser/";
    File file = new File(fileDir);
    boolean x = file.exists();
```

This code work properly

Answer (score 6):

To check if there is directory you have to use two conditions

```
File file = new File(filePath);
boolean isPresent = file.exists() && file.isDirectory();
```

> returns true only if file exists and is directory.

Comment: Have you read my quetion to the end???? I said that if i use `exists()` it create all path to the last file before check. Did you get my idea?

Comment: added lines in question

Comment: use `File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "nicknameOfUser");` instead of `context.getExternalFilesDir("/nicknameOfUser/")` and then check if `file.exists()` method

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for `isDirectory()` as follows :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/nicknameOfUser/");
  if(f.isDirectory()) {
 }
```

Comment: Have you read my quetion to the end???? I said that if i use `exists()` it create all path to the last file before check. Did you get my idea?

Comment: added lines in question

Comment: with `isDirectory()` also creates a new directory?

Comment: With all of that methods which was mentioned in question... They all create a new path with a new directory...

Answer (score 0):

```
 File file = new File("your path");
   file.exists();
```

Comment: Have you read my quetion to the end???? I said that if i use `exists()` it create all path to the last file before check. Did you get my idea?

Comment: added lines in question

Answer (score 0):

> But after i check .exists(); it create a path to the folder that i need a check... I DON'T NEED IT

The problem is not the `File.exists()` call.  It is the `getExternalFilesDir` call that is creating the directory.  As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> Unlike `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, the directory returned here will be automatically created for you.